# Как открыть файл pdf в новой вкладке для чтения?

Tags: html

```html
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");

$file = $_GET["file"] .".pdf";
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . urlencode($file));   
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");            
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
flush(); // this doesn't really matter.
$fp = fopen($file, "r");
while (!feof($fp))
{
    echo fread($fp, 65536);
    flush(); // this is essential for large downloads
} 
fclose($fp); 




<FilesMatch "\.pdf$">
ForceType applicaton/octet-stream
Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

```html
<a target="_blank" href="//site/file.pdf">Whitepaper</a>
```

Вот такой код он открывает и начинает скачивание как сделать просмотр?
Пробывал как в примере ниже ничего не работает он просто скачивается. Сайт на wordpress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если по клику начинается скачивание файла вместо открытия, то скорей всего сервер отдает заголовок:

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

чтобы открылся просмотр pdf в окне браузера сервер должен вернуть

```
Content-Type: application/pdf
```

Если файл отдается скриптом на стороне сервера, то надо реализовать в нем выбор правильного заголовка в зависимости от типа файла

Answer (score 0):

> Как открыть файл pdf в новой вкладке для чтения?

Гугл подсказывает, что вам надо поменять *attachment*

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . urlencode($file));
```

на *inline*

```
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=" . urlencode($file));
```

соответственно и здесь тоже:

```
<FilesMatch "\.pdf$">
ForceType applicaton/octet-stream
Header set Content-Disposition inline
</FilesMatch>
```